# C++ error: cannot declare variable 'block' to be of abstract type 'AABB'

Tags: c++

I just started writing a simple game in SFML 2.0.

I created class AABB with inheritance two class from SFML to write in class draw() method. 
But i get all the time this error:

```
\main.cpp|14|error: cannot declare variable 'block'  to    be of abstract type 'AABB'|
```

code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "headers/system.h"
#include "headers/AABB.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(50,50));

AABB block (shape);

System sys;

if(!sys.create())
{
    cout << "Critical error! Did you modified ini files?";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

sf::RenderWindow * WindowApp = sys.getHandle();

while (WindowApp->isOpen())
{


    sf::Event event;
    while (WindowApp->pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            WindowApp->close();
        if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            WindowApp->close();
    }

    WindowApp->draw(block);
    WindowApp->clear();
    WindowApp->display();

}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

AABB.h:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <SFML\Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML\Network.hpp>

using namespace std;


class AABB : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{

public:
    AABB(sf::Vector2f pos, sf::Vector2f size) :
        m_pos(pos),
        m_size(size) {}

    AABB(sf::RectangleShape shape) :
       m_sprite(shape)
        {}

private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target) const ;

private:

    sf::Vector2f m_size;
    sf::Vector2f m_pos;
    sf::RectangleShape m_sprite;
};
```

AABB.cpp

```
#include "../headers/AABB.h"

using namespace std;

void AABB::draw(sf::RenderTarget& target) const
{

    target.draw(m_sprite);

}
```

system class is not important here i think :D 
BTW when I remove inheritance from class app compile without errors.  What i suppose to do ? Please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `AABB` inherits `sf::Drawable`, which is an abstract class, and `AABB` does not override all pure virtual functions of it -- which would be necessary to make `AABB` a concrete class and to have objects of it. I suspect that this is the result of a typo. Where you write

```
virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target) const ;
```

in `AABB.h`, it should be

```
virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates) const ;
```

because the latter is the signature of `sf::Drawable`'s pure virtual function, as is described in the [SFML documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php#details). You will have to change the definition of this function in `AABB.cpp` as well, naturally.